# Products.Reflecto and Plone sharing, bug or feature?

Tags: plone

I'm using [Products.Reflecto](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.Reflecto/2.5.1) in Plone 4 to mirror file system content and provide fine-grained security on that content (i.e. give specific groups access to selected folders)

I know Reflecto objects are not real Plone content, however there is a *sharing* tab on all the files inside the Reflecto object. It works as expected, until you reindex the reflector at which point the settings are only applied to the reflector object.

E.g.:

- Mkdir (on the file system) -p test/foo/bar/baz
- Create a reflector object mirroring a "test" directory on the file system.
- Share "view" permission on baz with any user or group
- Verify that sharing works as expected
- Reindex "test"
- Notice that the user or group now has "view" permission on "foo"

Curiously, as soon as you configure sharing on a child object the reflector object has the same settings, but they seem to be ignored. Also curious, if you configure a "live" reflector sharing does not work at all. Is this a bug or a feature? Is it reasonable to try to support this use case? I.e. reindex the reflector and maintain sharing settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this was ever meant to work; I don't recall covering the use case when developing Reflecto in any case.

I haven't touched the product in years though, and I didn't do any more than glance at the code base to remind myself.

What I suspect in your test case is that the sharing information is set (via acquisition) on the reflector object, but the directory proxy for baz is being reindexed. If you were to reindex the reflector the sharing settings would no longer be ignored.

If so, then the presence of the sharing tab on the directory proxies is the real bug here.

Comment: Just to be clear: I share baz, and reindex "test" (the reflector object). Before reindex, sharing works. Afterward, it breaks (with sharing settings being applied to the reflector object "test" and not baz)

Comment: Also this is a two part question: is the current behavior a bug? and is it reasonable to attempt to support this use case in Plone? I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Well, the "I don't think this was ever meant to work" part is my way of saying "It's a bug, there never was a feature here".

Comment: Right and if I understand you correctly from our IRC conversation it's probably reasonable to try and support this feature in Plone. Thanks!